# theming information in drupal 9

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-9

In drupal 7 I used to get the theming information in views->advance settings->theming information-> rescan template.
I want to view the theming information in drupal 9.How to enable theming information in drupal 9.

Comment: This feature is not available for D8/9:
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2362413

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 9 for this you have to enable theme debugging. This will show you twig templating information like theme suggestions, hook and template location which is rendering the respective piece of data.

[image]

You enable Twig Debugging in sites/default/services.yml. Set the debug variable to true. And clear cache.

```
parameters:
  twig.config:
    debug: true
```

If services.yml does not yet exist then copy default.services.yml to services.yml.

Comment: While this is a good suggestion on how to view template suggestions generally.. it does not output theme suggestions for views (which the OP is specifically asking about). There is [an issue with proposed patches](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2923634), though it's taking quite a while to sort out

Answer (score 0):

That option is no longer provided in the views for Drupal8+ versions. You can enable Twig debugging and see template suggestions etc. by following this
https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates.
Alternatively, you can use this contributed module https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_debugger as well.